# Creating an installer for a swf

Tags: actionscript-3, installation, flash-cs6

I'm wondering what would be the best way to create an executable for my flash game I created. I think my question is pretty straightforward.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to simply publish a *.exe projector file from within Flash Pro.

Beyond that you can use a swf wrapper such as [MDM Zinc](http://www.multidmedia.com/) or [swf studio](http://www.northcode.com/).

As far as an installer goes you can check out [Inno Installer](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php/), which is not just for Flash.

You can also go the Adobe AIR route which addresses both packaging and installation.

**EDIT: where the setting is within Flash Pro:**

[image]

Comment: How can I publish my game as a .exe from within flash? In the publish settings I only have swf and swc formats. Thank you.

Comment: I see the option now. Thank you very much.